# Use the Shell Method to find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by the given curves and lines about the y-axis?

Tags: integration

$y= 8x^2$, $y=8 \sqrt {x}$

I know the limits are $0$ and $8$. But do I change the function so it's "$x=$" or leave it as it is?

Comment: The upper limit is $1$, not $8$.

Comment: By Andre Nicolas's comment,
$$V=16\pi\int^1_0x(x^2-\sqrt(x))dx=16\pi[\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{2x^{5/2}}{5}]^1_0$$

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture. The region we are rotating is caught between two parabolas. The region is vaguely lens-shaped.

The two curves meet where $8x^2=8\sqrt{x}$. That gives $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Now look at a slice of our region, perpendicular to the $x$-axis,  of width "$dx$", extending from $x$ to $x+dx$. The height of the slice is $8\sqrt{x}-8x^2$. Rotate about the $y$ axis. We get a cylindrical shell with radius $x$, height $8\sqrt{x}-8x^2$, and thickness $dx$, so volume $\approx 2\pi x(8\sqrt{x}-8x^2)\,dx$.

Now "add up" (integrate)  from $x=0$ to $x=1$. Our volume is
$$\int_0^1  2\pi x(8\sqrt{x}-8x^2)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of $y= 8x^2,y=8sqrtx$ are $(1,8),(0,0)$ and so
$$V=V_2-V_1=\int_0^1 2\pi x \cdot 8\sqrt xdx-\int_0^1 2\pi x \cdot 8x^2dx$$

Comment: you are right i have edited it many thanks@AndréNicolas